# How do I change the text of a button using data from a struct?

Tags: swift

So I am trying to change the text of my buttons in my UICollectionView cells using a struct I have defined, but I can't quite figure out how to do it, any help? I have tried a couple of things like a didSet and changing the text there but it didnt work

```
struct customData {
    var screenName: String
}
class orderViewController: UIViewController {
    let data = [
        customData(screenName: "Home"),
        customData(screenName: "Search"),
        customData(screenName: "Previous Orders"),
        customData(screenName: "Profile")
    ]
}
```

```
class customCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    var data: customData? {
        didSet {
            guard let data = data else {return}
            tabBar.titleLabel?.text = data.screenName
        }
    }
    fileprivate let tabBar: UIButton = {
        let segueButton = UIButton()
        segueButton.backgroundColor = .clear
        segueButton.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        segueButton.layer.cornerCurve = .continuous
        segueButton.setTitle("Test", for: .normal)
        segueButton.titleLabel?.font = FontKit.roundedFont(ofSize: 45, weight: .semibold)
        return segueButton
    }()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        contentView.addSubview(tabBar)
        tabBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tabBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        tabBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        tabBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        tabBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: contentView.frame.width, height: contentView.frame.height)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, in my didSet function, I changed the function to          tabBar.setTitle(data.screenName, for: .normal) and it set it

Comment: The idea of a button called `tabBar` is simply horrifying. Also, types such as your collection view cell subclass should start with a capital letter, e.g. CustomCell.

Comment: @matt haha yeah im making a custom tab bar thing on the top of the screen its weird, on this same topic, do you know how I could change the alpha of the text with a variable for my struct